# Pre-calculus : A test question with substitution and factoring

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, substitution

***QUESTION:*** Let $x \neq y$ and the relation between x and y follows;

$\frac{x^2-y}{x^2y+xy}=\frac{x-y^2}{xy^2}=x-y$   $ \quad $ then

what is the **exact** result of

$\frac{x^2+y}{x^2(y^2-y+1)}=?$

a) $y+1 \quad $  b)$\frac{1}{y} \quad $    c) $y^2 \quad $    d) $y^2-1\quad $    e) $y$

I have done so far ;

$\frac{x^2-y}{x^2y+xy}=\frac{x-y^2}{xy^2}$

$ \implies x(y-1)=1-y^2 $

**Case (if y=1):**
We use second part of equality which is

$\frac{x-y^2}{xy^2}=x-y$

$ \implies \frac{x-1}{x}=x-1$
$\implies $  $x=1 $ which is contradiction because our assumption is $x \neq y$. So $y \neq 1$

So we simplify our expression ;

$ x(y-1)=1-y^2  \implies  x=-(1+y)$  (this is the part that I stuck and I also don't understand by meaning of "exact result")

Thanks in advance for your guidances and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first two equations are
$$\frac{x^2-y}{xy(x+1)}=\frac{x-y^2}{xy^2}$$ multiplying by $xy\neq 0$ and $$x+1\neq 0$$ we obtain $$x^2y-y^2=(x-y^2)(x+1)$$
$$x^2y-y^2=x^2-xy^2+x-y^2$$
$$x^2y=x^2-xy^2+x$$ since $$x\neq 0$$ we have
$$xy=x-y^2+1$$
$$x(y-1)=1-y^2$$
this gives $$x(y-1)=-(y-1)(y+1)$$
first case: $$y=1$$
then we get
$$\frac{x-1}{x}=x-1$$
or $$(x-1)^2=0$$ thus $$x=1$$
and our term $$\frac{x^2+y}{x^2(y^2-y+1)}=2$$
the next case $$x+y+1=0$$ is for you!
next case: $$x+y+1=0$$ and we get $$x=-y-1$$ and we get
$$x-y^2=x^2y^2-xy^3$$
or
$$x(1+y^3)=y^2(x^2+1)$$
with $$x=-y-1$$ we get5
$$(1+y^3)(-y-1)=y^2(y^2+2y+2)$$
$$-y-y^4-1-y^3=y^4-2y^3+2y^2$$
$$0=2y^4+3y^3+2y^2+y+1$$
and this equation has no real solutions, if i have made no mistake!
i haven't made a mistake, therefore your problem has no real solutions!!
(My program gives the same solution!)

Comment: but our assumption is $x \neq y$ so, you also found that $x=1=y$ which is a contradiction

Comment: ok i oversee that , then $$x=y=1$$ is impossible, ok let me compute the case that $$x+y+1=0$$

Comment: Like $(w^3-1)=0$ and $w \neq 1$ then $w^2+w+1=?$  the question, w is not real number but we factor someways for the answer.